# Using space in pd.read_hdf column while reading

Tags: python, pandas, hdf

I have a HDF file, where a column name is "COL ABC"

I need to query it using pandas

```
> df = pd.read_hdf('test.h5', 'df', where=['COL ABC in ["Sample Condition"]'])
```

But I am getting an error with the "COL ABC" which has spaces in it, working fine with the other columns where spaces are not there.

Comment: Did you try where=['\'COL ABC\' in ["Sample Condition"]'] ?